# Installer to Install one or more programs

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer, installshield

We have around 8 different programs each with its own MSI / EXE installer.

What is the best way to create a single installer that will give users a list of the 8 different programs and then based on the apps the user wants to install they will start the installer one by one. The installer can run and just launch the app installers one by one and don't need to automatically install all the apps behind the scenes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used this http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Nullsoft scriptable install system

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the free InnoSetup for that. It also comes with Pascal scripting and is able to "temporarily" install your MSIs into a temp folder and execute them. Some scripting may be required to do so, but it is possible.

Comment: I have used `Inno` and I love that thing.

Comment: @ToughPal: I'm sorry, but no. Yet, there's a lot of information out there (Google) about how to achieve things with InnoSetup. Also, the manual included is very good. It should be easy for you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) would work really well for this.  I have a lot of users doing this where they create a sort of "umbrella" installer that simply contains all the bits of other installers.  It's very easy to create a custom panel that lets the user select which components to install and then execute the installer associated with those components.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for [dotnetinstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/).

It is a open source tool and easy to use. Am using this tool and works perfect for me.