# Single EXE file to install a group of software and loading files

Tags: struts2, windows-installer, bundle, installshield, exe

I have devoloped a [Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts) 2 web application. For running it on a server, I need to install the following:

- JDK
- [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)
- [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)

I need to sent my project to a foreign client. He asked me to convert my entire project and software into a single EXE file, so that using a single EXE file he could install everything and load my project into the server.

That is, he could be able to load the project on the server using that single exe. The EXE file will start invoking the installers one by one and finally load my project.

I have converted my .msi installers to .exe and my project into a [WAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29) file and my database into an .sql file. Now I want to combine everything into a single EXE file.

Is it possible to create such a single EXE file? What tools and steps do I have to follow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installer to Install one or more programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344568/installer-to-install-one-or-more-programs)

Comment: @KenWhite White Thanks for that link. That was useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a JDK, Tomcat and MySQL you need a setup authoring tool which supports prerequisites. Since you want a single EXE file, that setup tool must also embed the prerequisites in an EXE bootstrapper.

You didn't mention which setup tool you are using, but you can try one of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Additionally, the setup tool you choose should have SQL scripts support. Most tools don't have it.